# Генератор объектов JS

Tags: javascript, объекты

Нужно сделать генератор объектов, в его функции входят: добавление определенного количества объектов, добавление определенного количества свойств, добавление названия свойства объекта и его значения

```
let Objectq = {};
let arrObj = [];
let nameObject;
function createObject(){
    let countObjects = +prompt("Колличество объектов");
    for(let i = 0; i < countObjects; i++){
        nameObject = prompt("Введите название базы данных");
        let countProperties = +prompt("Введите колличество свойств");
        for(let i = 0; i < countProperties; i++){
            let key = prompt("Введите свойство");
            let value = prompt("Введите значение свойства");
            arrObj.push(key, value);
        }
        let strObj = arrObj.join("")
        console.log(strObj, typeof(strObj));
        console.log(arrObj, typeof(arrObj));

    }
}
createObject();
```

Застрял на этом моменте, я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы js принимал строку, и уже через JSON.parse делал мне объект {key: value, }

Comment: Свойства можно добавлять и проще...

obj['имя_свойства'] = 'значение'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Про "название базы данных" не совсем понял... Но вот такой вариант будет делать массив объектов.

```
const arrObj = [];
function createObject(){
    let countObjects = +prompt("Колличество объектов");
    for(let i = 0; i < countObjects; i++){
        const Objectq = {};
        //nameObject = prompt("Введите название базы данных");
        let countProperties = +prompt("Введите колличество свойств");
        for(let i = 0; i < countProperties; i++){
            let key = prompt("Введите свойство");
            let value = prompt("Введите значение свойства");
            Objectq[key] = value
        }
        arrObj.push(Objectq);
    }
    return arrObj
}
console.log(createObject())
```

Comment: Ну я сделал это для понятности, например, в название базы данных мы вводим "People", а значения задаем "age" и "name".